# How to split input value and insert into tspan

Tags: jquery

I want to split the text entered by user in input text box and append into tspan of svg text

Example:

```
<input type="text" autofocus/>
```

Text entered would be for example: "I have some text that wraps onto three lines in this container"

I want to get my jquery/javascript to parse those lines and turn it into this:

```
<text text-anchor="start" y="152">
<tspan x="212" dy="-15">I have some text that</tspan>
<tspan x="212" dy="20">wraps onto three </tspan>
<tspan x="212" dy="22">lines in this container</tspan>
</text>
```

Note: Text would be split based on width minus 5px of svg shape to keep text inside borders

So far I tried this:

```
            var output;
            window.onchange = onchange;
            function onchange(e)
            {
                output = e.target.value;
                var width = e.target.value.length;
                var element = document.getElementById("text");
                var height = element.clientHeight;
                console.log("Width of text:" + width);
                console.log("Height of text:" + height);
                console.log("Text entered: " + output);

                var words  = output.split(/[ ,]+/);
                console.log(words );
                e.target.value = '';
            }

            var el = document.getElementById("rect"); // or other selector like querySelector()
            var rect = el.getBoundingClientRect(); // get the bounding rectangle

            console.log("Width of rect: " + rect.width);
            console.log("Height of rect: " + rect.height);

            $("input[type='text']").bind('keydown', function () {
                $(this).attr("size", Math.max(5, $(this).val().length));
            });
```

Comment: What does it have to do with d3 and joint, though?

Comment: I am going to convert some of the logic to d3 and jointjs later. I am working mostly on svg implementation using them. Thought some one might post any ideas

Comment: See http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7555321

Answer (score 0):

try underscore templates, and it seems like you are making this more complicated than it needs to be (I do that too; so I know)

Comment: templates takes only html and renders html if I am not wrong. What I need is svg text and its tspan

Answer (score 0):

On SVG multiline text, it's a little tricky. You need to split it manually and assign it to  tag. Mike's site has an example [Wrapping Long Labels](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7555321).

Here its a working code I adapted time ago:

```
<!doc html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<header>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>

<style>
svg {
    border:1px solid #999;
}
.axis {
  font: 18px Helvetica;
  text-anchor:middle;
}
</style>

</header>
<body>
<script>
var margin = {top: 20, right: 120, bottom: 20, left: 120},
    width = 960 - margin.right - margin.left,
    height = 450 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
var tex = ["I have some text that wraps onto three lines in this container"];

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.right + margin.left)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g");

svg.append("text")
      .attr("class", "axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" +(width/2)+ "," + (height /2) + ")")
      .text(tex[0])
     .selectAll("text") 
d3.selectAll("text").call(wrap, 100); /* your container width */

function wrap(text, width) {
  text.each(function() {
    var text = d3.select(this),
        words = text.text().split(/\s+/).reverse(),
        word,
        line = [],
        lineNumber = 0,
        lineHeight = 1.1, // ems
        y = text.attr("y"),
        dy = parseFloat(text.attr("dy")),
        tspan = text.text(null).append("tspan").attr("x", 0).attr("y", y).attr("dy", 0 + "em");
    while (word = words.pop()) {
      line.push(word);
      tspan.text(line.join(" "));
      if (tspan.node().getComputedTextLength() > width) {
        line.pop();
        tspan.text(line.join(" "));
        line = [word];
        tspan = text.append("tspan").attr("x", 0).attr("y", y).attr("dy", lineHeight +  "em").text(word);
        console.log(lineNumber);
      }
    }
  }
)};

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

And [here](http://jsfiddle.net/w08frwyh/) the jsFiddle.

And [this one with an input box](http://jsfiddle.net/pnzfbqrj/)

If you want to go all the way with d3, can use d3 selector:

```
.... body ...

<input type="text" id="inputText">
<button type="submit" id="send"  onclick="goText();" >update</button>

.... script ...

function goText() {
    var textVal = d3.selectAll("#inputText").property("value");
    d3.selectAll("text").text(textVal).call(wrap, 100);
}
```

A tipical SVG multi-line text looks like this:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">

    <text x="20" y="10">
        <tspan>tspan line 1</tspan>
        <tspan dx="30" dy="10">tspan line 2</tspan>
    </text>
</svg>
```

Rather than having to position each line of text absolutely, the  element makes it possible to position a line of text relatively to the previous line of text with "dx" and "dy" starting at "x" and "y". So, the previous example give you:

```
x/y    20         50
10     tspan line 1
20                tspan line 2 <=[x+dx=20+30=50][y+dy=10+10=20]
```

If text is null "*while (word = words.pop()) {*" do nothing.-

Hope this help.

Comment: what is text.text(null)?

Comment: and what is tspan.node().?

Comment: Also what is the use of `y = text.attr("y"),`

Comment: bind on ("change") => update text, call wrap function. _$("#inputText").on("change", function () {_

Comment: If you want inmediate update _$("#inputText").on("keyup", function () {_

Comment: But on change function would append `<text>` tag each time when on-change event is called right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85144/discussion-between-klaujesi-and-angulardirective).